# Empty Row with datalength 3

Tags: sql-server

I have table with empty rows which I don't need. so I have removed the rows by using a condition

```
where txtfield <>''.
```

This deletes all empty rows BUT there's one row which is not removed. I tried using Null condition but no success.

when I check the length of this row, it's 3 unlike other empty rows which have

```
  datalength =0
```

I also tried using trim function but no success.

e.g.

```
 trim(txtfield) <>''
    ltrim(rtrim(txtfield)) <>''
    txtfield is not null
```

Please help me in finding out why the row with no data has length 3 and how to exclude it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the ASCII function to check what characters you actually have.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(myCol,1,1)) as c1,
       ASCII(SUBSTRING(myCol,2,1)) as c2,
       ASCII(SUBSTRING(myCol,3,1)) as p3
FROM myTable
```

Then you can delete the row like this for example:

```
DELETE myTable
WHERE myCol = char(98) + char(32) + char(41)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!! that worked like  a charm...….the row was using horizontal tab, ASCII 09.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function in where clause.

```
DELETE...
WHERE REPLACE(txtfield, ' ', '') <> ''
```